# SQL loop through a table and find the next part record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Not sure where to start on this one.  I inheriated a table that has a list of part numbers that are are active and inactive. If the part number is inactive, they enter the next valid part number. If the part number is active there is no Next PartNumber.  They want to search on a Part Number and find all of the next part numbers that match.

Basically the table looks like this. 
PartNumber Varchar(20),   Active Varchar(3),   NextPartNumber Varchar(20).

Problem is I do not know how many part numbers are in the chain.  Here is a sample of the data:

```
100X   No   XYZ
XYZ    No   45A6
45A6   Yes  

QWER   No   RT98
RT98   No   POUL1
POUL1  No   N9HGT
N9HGT  No   FGH12
FGH12  Yes
```

I can write a query like this, but since I don't know how many part numbers there are, this won't work.

```
Select A.PartNumber, A.NextPartNumber, B.PartNumber, B.NextPartNumber, C.PartNumber, C.NextPartNumber
FROM tblPartTable as A
inner join
tblPartTable as B
on A.PartNumber = B.NextPartNumber
inner join
tblPartTable as C
on B.PartNumber = C.NextPartNumber
where A.PartNumber = '100X'
```

Comment: Which DB and what language are you accessing the DB with?

Comment: Use a loop, unless your DBMS doesn't support it.

Comment: Recursive CTE (Common table Expression) would allow you to get n rows but not all RDBMS support CTE (mySQL being one that doesn't)  Oracle can do this with  `connect by prior` syntax as well.  This is a hierichal query depending on rdbms, determines approach & syntax

Comment: Please tag with mysql, sql-server, or oracle, to indicate the DBMS system.

Comment: tell the person that designed this table that storing "Yes" and "No" as strings is a poor practice.

Comment: Sorry SQL Server 2008

Comment: Tag it accordingly which assure an accurate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SQL Server (which I'm assuming you're talking about since your earlier questions have been about it), you can use a recursive common table expression to easily get the searched for part and all its successors, there is no need to loop manually;

```
WITH cte AS (
  -- Base condition, where do we start the search?
  SELECT t.* FROM tblPartTable t WHERE t.PartNumber = '100X'
  UNION ALL
  -- Continue condition, how do we find the next part from the current one?
  SELECT t.* FROM tblPartTable t JOIN cte ON t.PartNumber = cte.NextPartNumber
)
SELECT partnumber, active FROM cte;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ecc6/2).

The same query works on most RDBMS's except MySQL.